# Minimization using the penalty method

Tags: optimization

I dont understand what was made between step (1) and step (2). How did they managed to get to (2)? I tried solving both equations in order of x1 and then solve the equality to find x2 in order of p but i dont get the same thing.

[image]

Comment: It is just a matter of carefully grinding through the equation. You can make some observations to simplify matters like $x_1 = 2 x_2$ is immediate from the equations.